# Integrating over homotopy classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

We know that $ֿ\pi_2(\mathbb{S}^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. Given a fixed degree, say $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, is there a standard, conventional way to parametrize continuous maps $\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ which have degree $n$?

It is pretty clear that the identity map (in spherical coordinates) $(\theta,\varphi)\mapsto(\theta,\varphi)$ generates the group and furthermore, $$(\theta,\varphi)\mapsto(n\theta,\varphi)$$ yields a representatative in the homotopy class of degree $n$. Is there some way of starting off from that map and somehow enumerating all possible deformations of that map which keep you in the same homotopy class? For example, it is clear that one of these parameters is simply a choice of member of $SO(3)$ which picks the initial orientation of the map above.

Ideally I would like a decomposition (into a sum of two functions, or a composition of two functions), one of which has degree $n$ and is somehow special to that homotopy class and the other has degree zero, and enumerating it is the same for all $n$.

Does something like that exist already?

Comment: Actually this was a deleted answer, here is a somehow canonical map with degree $n$, but for now it is not clear how to get the decomposition you ask.

Write $S^{2} = \mathbb{CP}^1$ then define $$F_{n}: \mathbb{CP}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$$ by $$F_{n}=([x:y]) = ([x^n+y^n:x^n-y^n]).$$ I leave you to check that it is well defined and has degree $n$ (just count the preimages of a generic point in $\mathbb{CP}^1$).


Note actually that for dimension $3$ there is an even nicer choice, write $S^3$ as the unit quaternions, the map $q \mapsto q^k$ is a map of the 3-sphere with degree $k$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, assuming all maps are pointed, you're interested in studying the space $\Omega^2 S^2$, possibly via the map $\pi_0: \Omega^2 S^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$.  Certainly as a loop space it's true that the fibers of $\pi_0$, i.e., the components of $\Omega^2 S^2$ are all homotopy equivalent, say to $\Omega^2_0 S^2$, but I don't think there is an easy parametrization of $\Omega^2_0 S^2$.

Comment: @JHF, Yes, I suppose there is a natural topology on $\Omega^2\mathbb{S}^2$, and one would like to integrate over this manifold. The hope would be to re-write that integration measure as the product measure over the two spaces $\Omega_0^2\mathbb{S}^2$ and the quotient space $\Omega^2\mathbb{S}^2 / \Omega_0^2\mathbb{S}^2$, if that makes any vague sense...